# flex tree icon indicator

Tags: apache-flex, tree, icons

I want to add an indicator on a tree node icon , meaning , for example like in eclipse when there is an error the icon get a special small indicator on the regular icon.
how can i do that?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new icon for each tree icon state and set the iconFunction property for the Tree.

Comment: i want to be able to do it in runtime and not make all the options for each indicator that i will want in the future...

Comment: Then create a custome treeItemRenderer and add a new Image over the current icon. You can check the flex sdk source code for the TreeItemRenderer class and update it from there :)

Comment: i would prefer not to change the renderer, is there any possibility of combining the 2 images into 1 and then set it as the icon?

Comment: something like this http://webdevotion.be/blog/2009/08/05/how-to-merge-two-images-into-one-in-actionscript/

Comment: Why not to create a new renderer is soooo easy to do it!  http://pudgylogic.blogspot.de/2009/07/custom-itemrenderer-for-tree-control-in.html   http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_8.html